# jQuery selectmenu not working with knockout.js when embedded inside a 'visible' binding

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, knockout.js, select-menu

I have a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem at: http://jsfiddle.net/michaelajohnsonwa/sDchM/7/

The generated dropdown elements from the select when hidden don't seem to be generated correctly. I have tried using both the 'options' binding and the custom jqOptions binding. I tried added in .selectmenu('refresh') to the mix but there was no difference in the outcome. The custom binding doesn't work when used within a template binding which I also find curious.

I'm not sure if this is problem with jQuery selectmenu or knockout.js.

--edit: just discovered the working code doesn't work in IE. Chrome and Firefox do demonstrate the problem accurately.

Any help here will be appriciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Menu plugin will not work correctly in hidden elements, so it should be called like this.

```
if(obj.isVisible()) {
    $('#outterContainer').show();
    $('#broken2').selectmenu();
}
```

EDIT:
It happens because of the incorrect dimensions of the hidden element. So this can be fixed by giving the dimension of the select element.

```
$('#broken2').selectmenu({width:"200px"});
```

please see it : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/sDchM/17/

Comment: Thank Diode!! I've updated the jsfiddle with your answer working (http://jsfiddle.net/michaelajohnsonwa/sDchM/8/). I can't say I'm happy with the answer though. I means need to manually handle each dropdown and when you consider a wizard of multiple steps with multiple dropdowns you lose the advantage of the declarative binding to the viewmodel.

Comment: Beautiful!! Thanks Diode!! You've made me very happy!! Great answer!!